# Redirect between html, jsp without changing the URL

Tags: html, jsp, model-view-controller, web

I am planning to design a web application with multiple HTML and JSP pages. The first page of myapp (index.html) loads up with the url

> localhost:8080/mywebapp

without an explicitly pointing it to

> localhost:8080/mywebapp.index.html

because web-xml has index.html in its startup script. Thats perfectly fine!

But how to toggle between multiple JSPs and HTMLs that are in the web app keeping the URL constant

> localhost:8080/mywebapp

The user should not be knowing the navigation pattern when he is using the web-app.
Ideas on any frameworks or implementations are highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that you shouldn't do this, essentially what you have to do is bypass the standard routing method of your application.

You can do this one of two ways.

1) Use Ajax to call all the different URLs you need from within a single page. This will give you the single URL you're looking for though it doesn't of course prevent anyone from trivially working out what the actual navigation URLs are and unless you build a single page app and do some really evil interdependencies finding your navigation is trivially easy.

2) Your second option would be to create a single servlet which takes parameters which identify which part of your application you want to use. If you really wanted to be horribly evil you could hash those arguments with some form of per user short duration cookie so that even if they identify the actual web calls you're making running them manually won't actually work.

Comment: Thank you Chris, Your answer made a lot of sense. To clarify,
Will the Ajax call to the other page change the URL where the browser points to or not?

Comment: @VinayAbhishekManchiraju No it doesnt :)